# Is it possible to receive mail send response from java using TCP/IP protocall?

Tags: jakarta-mail, tcp

I want to test mail sending. As TCP/IP protocall may be supported to give a response of sent mail, I want to know about is there any library to use it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you understand how email works.  TCP/IP is used to send the message from your application to your mail server.  Your mail server then forwards the message to other mail servers, which ultimately deliver the message to the recipient.  There's no end-to-end TCP connection between your application and the recipient's mail server.  JavaMail will tell you whether whether the message was accepted by your mail server, but not whether it was delivered by the recipient's mail server.

There's more information in the [JavaMail FAQ](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#badaddr).

Comment: do you mean if there have no exception coming from JavaMail API, that means it is accepted but not ensured proper delivery? if that so, is there any way to get delivery response?